# How can one spread the result of foreachRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

let's say I have a code as follows :

```
var model = initiliazeModel(some_params)
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    model = model.update(rdd)
    println(model) 
}
println(model) // or doing some thing on the model
```

My problem is that even if the first println gives the desired result ie. the model up-to-date, the second println displays the initialized model and not the updated one !!!

My question is how can I spread the updated model outside the block foreachRDD ?!

I also think of a synchronization problem because the 2nd println is run before the 1st one !!!

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

You have a common misconception here. In general, when you call map, filter, foreach, and any other transformation, you are not executing anything just yet. You closures are sent to executors and the stages configured, but all things are evaluated lazily. Your main program proceed ahead, either adding more configuration or other things, not waiting for all computations to be done. Thus, when your program reaches your second println (miliseconds after), the model has not changed nor has any other println been called.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but still not know how to solve this problem (how can I for example save the final model)?!

Comment: Well, I was answering the question :-) As for the underlying problem, generally speaking, you push the RDDs somewhere else (file, socket, db). Check https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams

Comment: For me, as I can not have the model up-to-date on the outside of foreachRDD block, my problem is not yet solved (I need to do some operations on the updated model outside the foreachRDD bloc) !!!

Comment: chain another foreach block or other transformation. Remember, you are using a distributed platform, the logic has to go to the data and not the other way around ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, I have no idea, but in Java, you can enclose your foreach and model variable within a class as a static members and then use model variable after the success of foreach in another class.

Answer (score 0):

Accumulators are global in Spark. you can update the accumulator variable anywhere in the Program and it gets reflects everywhere regardless of wether it is different executor or driver program.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()     
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

creating and initilizing Accumulator

```
 val accumulator = sc.accumulator(0)
```

Initializing the accumulator

```
accumulator.add(1)
```

accessing the latest value

```
accumulator.value
```

hope this helps